# How to pause or stop the media when other music player is active?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I have created a hybrid android app in Ionic framework which has some audio files in it and this music player is customized with org.apache.cordova.media plugin.

If I start to play the default phone music player while the my app music player is running, both the audio is playing.

Does anyone knows how to stop the app music player when I run the default mobile player and vice-versa?

Comment: this is the official way to gain and loose audio focus....
http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html